# Jquery selecting check box by click on text in a table td

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am trying to check and uncheck checkbox by clicking on text next to it. Here is the example in which i am trying to click on item name and checkbox should be selected. I think toggle should fit here but I am unable to make it work.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chandrashekarthota/VnnUF/)

```
$("#checkall").change(function () {
  $(this).closest("table").find(".checkbox").attr("checked", this.checked).change();
});

$(".checkbox").change(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass("highlight", this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are targeting the fileName, if so then try

```
$("#checkall").change(function () {
    $(this).closest("table").find(".checkbox").prop("checked", this.checked).change();
});

$(".checkbox").change(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass("highlight", this.checked);
});

$('.filename').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input').prop('checked', function (i, c) {
        return !c;
    }).change()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Cuhg5/)

- have a click handler for the td with the target text
- find the input element in the same row and toggle its checked state

Comment: What does return !c do here?

Comment: @Chandana the method gets the curernt value of the checked property - true/false we negate the value using `!c` and returns that as the new value

Comment: I have issue in my project. Select all and un select all is working only one time. I googled to some extent that attr is not good one to use and to use prop. but it did not work for me with above code. Could you please help?

Comment: @Chandana it depends on the jquery version you are using... what is the jQuery version used in the project

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chandana2014/Cuhg5/4/ this is updated fiddle with jquery updated version